# Disable mouse event (click) whilst actions are performed

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

I'm currently design an application that when a button is pressed it expands to display further information. A major issue I am faced with is that if the button is pressed whilst contracting so that it expands again, the co-ordinates are saved from when it was clicked, meaning it will never return to its original state.

I either need a way of disabling the mouse click on the button whilst the TweenMax is doing its job in contracting the button, or by extracting the coordinates from an array.

I've managed to get the array of coordinates from my menu class into the main class, but can't work out the best way in order to stop the problem from occurring.

--

```
expand = false;
(run menu function)
item.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, boxExCo);

private function boxExCo(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (!expand)
    {
        selectedBox = e.target as Box;
        boxX = selectedBox.x;
        boxY = selectedBox.y;
        expand = true;
        TweenMax.to.... (expand)
    }
    else
    {
        expand = false;
        TweenMax.to... (contract to coordinates)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `item.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, boxExCo);` when you no longer want the event to be able to fire, and then just add it back on using

`item.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, boxExCo);` when you want the event to be able to fire again.

Once you start your tween max, remove the event.

Once it is finished, add the event back on.

Comment: I tried this but couldn't get it to work. I first tried it using the onComplete attribute with TweenMax, and then adding it either side of the tweening, but was never effective. Have you any ideas how to implement it failing my efforts?

Comment: You should remove the event right before you start the tween. Then on the you should add an `Event.COMPELTE` to the tween and add the mouse event back in that event listener function.